# How to identify issue when build linphone on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-18.04, linphone

I am building a sip server using the latest code version 2.1 of Flexisip opensource: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/flexisip/tree/release/2.1

When follow the instruction Building Flexisip with CMake, I got the error as below when using command `make -C ./build -j 5`
:

```
[ 50%] Building C object linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/grammars/belle_sip_messageParser.c.o
cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/build.make:663: recipe for target 'linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/grammars/belle_sip_messageParser.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/grammars/belle_sip_messageParser.c.o] Error 4
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2242: recipe for target 'linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
```

I'm new to all kind of make build command and flexsip so I really confused on what is the real issue here or how to report and identify the real bug. Can somebody please help me with this.

**My enviroment:** (if you want to know more, please comment so I can add it!)

- Ubuntu 18.04

**Result of command** `cmake -S . -B ./build`:

```
-- Setting install rpath to /opt/belledonne-communiactions/lib
-- Config dir: /etc/flexisip
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "1.1.1")
-- Configuring SOCI:
-- SOCI_VERSION                             = 4.0.0
-- SOCI_ABI_VERSION                         = 4.0
-- SOCI_SHARED                              = ON
-- SOCI_STATIC                              = OFF
-- SOCI_FRAMEWORK                           =
-- SOCI_TESTS                               = OFF
-- SOCI_ASAN                                = OFF
-- SOCI_CXX_C11                             =
-- LIB_SUFFIX                               = 64
-- Looking for SOCI dependencies:
-- CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT                   = -lpthread
-- MySQL:
-- Found MySQL: /usr/include/mysql, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
-- MySQL Embedded not found.
-- MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR                        = /usr/include/mysql
-- MYSQL_LIBRARIES                          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
-- ODBC: disabled, since WITH_ODBC=OFF
-- Oracle: disabled, since WITH_ORACLE=OFF
-- PostgreSQL:
-- POSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIRS                  = /usr/include/postgresql
-- POSTGRESQL_LIBRARIES                     = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so
-- POSTGRESQL_VERSION                       = 10.18 (Ubuntu 10.18-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
-- SQLite3:
CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/cmake-3.21.3-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (SQLITE3)
  does not match the name of the calling package (SQLite3).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  linphone-sdk/external/soci/cmake/modules/FindSQLite3.cmake:57 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  linphone-sdk/external/soci/cmake/dependencies/SQLite3.cmake:3 (find_package)
  linphone-sdk/external/soci/cmake/SociDependencies.cmake:74 (include)
  linphone-sdk/external/soci/CMakeLists.txt:84 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR                      = /usr/include
-- SQLITE3_LIBRARIES                        = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so
-- Firebird: disabled, since WITH_FIREBIRD=OFF
-- DB2: disabled, since WITH_DB2=OFF
-- Configuring SOCI core library:
-- SOCI_CORE_TARGET                         = soci_core
-- SOCI_CORE_TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME             = soci_core
-- SOCI_CORE_DEPS_LIBS                      = -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so
-- SOCI_CORE_INCLUDE_DIRS                   = /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include/private /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci/src/core
-- WITH_BOOST                               =
-- COMPILE_DEFINITIONS                      = SOCI_ABI_VERSION="4.0" HAVE_DL=1 SOCI_LIB_PREFIX="libsoci_" SOCI_LIB_SUFFIX=".so" SOCI_DEBUG_POSTFIX=""
--
-- Configuring SOCI backend libraries:
-- Found MySQL: /usr/include/mysql, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
-- MySQL Embedded not found.
CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/cmake-3.21.3-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (SQLITE3)
  does not match the name of the calling package (SQLite3).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  linphone-sdk/external/soci/cmake/modules/FindSQLite3.cmake:57 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  linphone-sdk/external/soci/src/backends/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- MySQL - SOCI backend for MySQL
-- SOCI_MYSQL                               = ON
-- SOCI_MYSQL_TARGET                        = soci_mysql
-- SOCI_MYSQL_OUTPUT_NAME                   = soci_mysql
-- SOCI_MYSQL_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS           = SOCI_ABI_VERSION="4.0" HAVE_DL=1
-- SOCI_MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES           = /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include/private /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include/private /usr/include/mysql
-- PostgreSQL - SOCI backend for PostgreSQL
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL                          = ON
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_TARGET                   = soci_postgresql
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_OUTPUT_NAME              = soci_postgresql
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS      = SOCI_ABI_VERSION="4.0" HAVE_DL=1
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES      = /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include/private /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include/private /usr/include/postgresql /usr/include/postgresql
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_NOSINLGEROWMODE          =
-- SQLite3 - SOCI backend for SQLite 3
-- SOCI_SQLITE3                             = ON
-- SOCI_SQLITE3_TARGET                      = soci_sqlite3
-- SOCI_SQLITE3_OUTPUT_NAME                 = soci_sqlite3
-- SOCI_SQLITE3_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS         = SOCI_ABI_VERSION="4.0" HAVE_DL=1
-- SOCI_SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES         = /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include/private /home/ubuntu/flexisip/linphone-sdk/external/soci/include/private /usr/include /usr/include
--
--
-- Package file name is SOCI-4.0.0
-- Package file name is JOSE-1.0.0
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found suitable version "2.17.1", minimum required is "1.7.10")
-- Setting packaging install prefix to /opt/belledonne-communiactions
-- Could NOT find MbedTLS (missing: MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIRS MBEDTLS_LIBRARIES)
-- DTLS SRTP not available
-- Could NOT find GSM (missing: GSM_INCLUDE_DIRS GSM_LIBRARIES HAVE_GSM_GSM_H)
CMake Warning at linphone-sdk/mediastreamer2/CMakeLists.txt:197 (message):
  Could not find GSM library, mediastreamer2 will be compiled without the GSM
  codec.


-- Could NOT find Opus (missing: OPUS_INCLUDE_DIRS OPUS_LIBRARIES HAVE_OPUS_OPUS_H)
CMake Warning at linphone-sdk/mediastreamer2/CMakeLists.txt:211 (message):
  Could not find opus library, mediastreamer2 will be compiled without the
  OPUS codec.


-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.17.1")
-- 'pystache' python module found
-- 'six' python module found
-- MSGPACK not found
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found suitable version "1.1.1", minimum required is "0.9.8")
-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * DL
 * Speex
 * Git
 * PkgConfig

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * MySQL
 * PostgreSQL
 * SQLite3
 * Jansson
 * SRTP (required version >= 2)
 * SpeexDsp
 * Sqlite3
 * XML2
 * ZLIB
 * PythonInterp (required version >= 3)
 * Doxygen
 * LibNgHttp2
 * XercesC
 * Hiredis
 * Threads
 * Protobuf
 * OpenSSL (required version >= 0.9.8)

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * MbedTLS
 * GSM
 * Opus
 * Iconv

-- Startup scripts configured with bindir=/opt/belledonne-communiactions/bin
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build
```

**Full Result of command** `make -C ./build -j 5`:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target bnf
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target url
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target sdp
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target ipt
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target msg
[  1%] Built target sdp
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[  2%] Built target ipt
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[  2%] Built target bnf
[  3%] Built target url
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target sresolv
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target stun
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[  5%] Built target msg
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[  5%] Built target sresolv
[  6%] Built target stun
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target soci_core
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target su
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target bcunit
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target jose
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target bctoolbox
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[  7%] Built target bcunit
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 11%] Built target jose
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 13%] Built target soci_core
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 18%] Built target su
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 19%] Built target bctoolbox
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 19%] Built target linphone-doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
CMake Warning at /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/bctoolbox/BcGitVersion.cmake:43 (message):
  Project version (5.0.0) and git tag (5.0.26) differ.  Please put them
  identical


make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 19%] Built target ms2-git-version
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target features
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 19%] Built target ms2-basedescs-header
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 19%] Built target features
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 19%] Built target flexisip-git-version
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target addrinfo
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 19%] Built target addrinfo
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target localinfo
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target http
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 20%] Built target localinfo
CMake Warning at /home/ubuntu/flexisip/build/linphone-sdk/bctoolbox/BcGitVersion.cmake:43 (message):
  Project version (5.0.0) and git tag (5.0.24) differ.  Please put them
  identical


make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 20%] Built target liblinphone-git-version
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target sip
[ 22%] Built target http
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target soci_mysql
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target soci_postgresql
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target soci_sqlite3
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 22%] Built target ms2-voipdescs-header
[ 25%] Built target sip
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 26%] Built target soci_mysql
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 28%] Built target soci_postgresql
[ 29%] Built target soci_sqlite3
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target belr
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target ortp
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target iptsec
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target nea
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 29%] Built target linphone-cxx-wrapper
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 30%] Built target belr
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 31%] Built target nea
[ 32%] Built target iptsec
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target nta
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target nth
[ 36%] Built target ortp
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target soa
[ 36%] Built target nta
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 37%] Built target nth
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target tport
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target nua
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 38%] Built target soa
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 40%] Built target tport
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 40%] Built target linphone-cpp-html-doc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 42%] Built target nua
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target portbind
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 42%] Built target portbind
[ 42%] Built target sofia-sip-ua
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target mediastreamer
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target bellesip
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
[ 50%] Built target mediastreamer
[ 50%] Building CXX object linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/sdp/parser.cc.o
[ 50%] Building C object linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/grammars/belle_sip_messageParser.c.o
cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/build.make:663: recipe for target 'linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/grammars/belle_sip_messageParser.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/grammars/belle_sip_messageParser.c.o] Error 4
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2242: recipe for target 'linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [linphone-sdk/belle-sip/src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/flexisip/build'
```

Comment: ¿How much RAM does the build machine have? ¿Are you sure that it is capable of running 5 (-j 5) compilers simultaneously?

Comment: @user7860670 It's have 1.9Gb RAM but i'm sure it not the problem cause I also run it with ```make -C ./build``` and it got same bug result.

Comment: 1.9Gb RAM is like nothing. Most likely gcc just runs out of memory and is getting killed. Try building on machine with at least 32 Gb RAM.

Comment: @user7860670 Ok i will try it and tell you back.

Comment: @user7860670 You are right, sir. If you write down the answer I will accept it.